# How to show that the metric in the tangent space is independent from the chart you take?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, differential-geometry, manifolds

I want to prove that for vectors $v_1,v_2 \in T_aM$ the euclidean length and distance is independent from the chart we are using, where $M$ is a submanifold in some $\mathbb{R}^n$

My problem is that I do not know how to bring the chart into play here. What does it have to do with the inner product in $T_aM$?

Comment: How are you defining $T_aM$?

Comment: with curves. So it is the set of velocity vectors of curves that go through this point on the manifold.

Comment: How do charts come into that definition?

Comment: charts were used to construct the manifold. the thing is that we never actually defined the inner product. our prof only said once (he did not write it down) that you could pull things back from the tangent space and then apply euclidean inner product and so on. but since charts do not actually go into the tangent space, I thought that I would ask this hear, how the inner product in tangent spaces is canonically defined?

Comment: In general the  task is to define an inner product on the tangent space which works on every space (a *smooth section of the inner product bundle*, known as a Riemannian metric). But certainly what your teacher is asking is simpler than all that. As it is, it is mostly a question about how he/she wants you to define the inner product. Might be a question for your teacher.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A submanifold $M$ of a Riemannian manifold $N$ naturally inherits the Riemannian   metric from $N$, because the tangent space $T_aM$ can be seen as a subspace of the tangent space $T_aN$. With your curve-based definition of tangent spaces this is abundantly clear: a curve in $M$ is also a curve in $N$. The inner product on $T_aM$ 
 is simply the restriction of the inner product on $T_aN$. In your case $N$ is $\mathbb R^n$.

Since no choice of charts is made in this process, we do not have to prove that the construction is independent of the choice of a chart.